# solr version that retrieve and rank uses on bluemix

Tags: ibm-cloud, solrj, ibm-watson, retrieve-and-rank

How to verify what version of solr is being used by Retrieve and Rank service on Bluemix in order to refer exact version of solr api and documentation of Solr.

Comment: Sasikanth, welcome to Stack Overflow. The primary purpose of Stack Overflow is to answer technical programming questions. Questions like yours about the capabilities of vendors' offerings are usually voted down or removed. Your question is a good one to ask on IBM's developerWorks Answers forum (https://developer.ibm.com/answers/smartspace/watson/).

For a better idea of how to use Stack Overflow, check out these tips on what topics to ask about - http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic - and what makes a good question - http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the Solr docs?https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/

Comment: As Ralph says, you should get a better chance of an answer to this sort of question on developer.ibm.com/answers - a specific example for your question would be https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/297800/what-is-the-solr-version-used-in-ibm-retrieve-and/